# How do I put a date function in a Complex Query that is made by joins?

Tags: sql, function, date

My Query is:

```
SELECT
  c.aCustID AS 'Contact ID',
  o.[FldDate22526] AS 'Opportunity Date',
  o.[FldNumeric22532] AS 'Opportunity Allotted to',
  n.tOpportunityname AS 'Opportunity Name',
  p.[FldString22540] AS 'Opportunity Phone',
  p.[FldString22539] AS 'Opportunity Address',
  r.[FldString22543] AS 'Opportunity Remerks (Customer Care)',
  p.[FldString22538] AS 'Opportunity Remerks (Sales)',
  o.[FldNumeric22536] AS 'Opportunity Status (5 Day)'
FROM
  tblCustomer AS c
  JOIN [tblObjectType3_3] as o
    ON c.aCustID = o.nID
  JOIN tblOpportunity AS n
    ON o.nID = n.aOpportunityID
  JOIN [tblObjectType3_11] AS p
    ON o.nID= p.nID
  JOIN [tblObjectType3_2] AS r
    ON p.nID = r.nID
```

Comment: What do you want to do with a date function? BTW those are the worst field names I've ever seen.. I assume you are not in a position to change them :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that all you want to do is limit your results to those in a date range.  For example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE o.[FldDate22526] > sysdate
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE o.[FldDate22526] BETWEEN now() and now()-7
```

Not sure which DB, so not sure which date syntax to use.